# Pass Bash comma delimited string values variable to jq arg filter

Tags: bash, jq, github-actions

I am trying to filter data from a json file using jq with a filter based on a dynamic list of values from within a Bash script.

The following jq command works by itself:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.name==("value1","value2"))' file.json
```

In Bash the following command works if I set the variable to a single value and pass it in

```
testValue="value1"
result=$(jq -r --arg TESTVALUE "$testValue" '.[] | select(.name==($TESTVALUE))' file.json)
echo "$result"
```

If I set the variable to a comma delimited list of values and pass it in it returns no results

```
testValues="\"value1\", \"value2\""
result=$(jq -r --arg TESTVALUES "$testValues" '.[] | select(.name==($TESTVALUES))' file.json)
echo "$result"
```

I am a novice in bash scripting, so I am sure I am missing something simple in how the variable is being interpreted.  I have included the file.json below as well.

```
[
    {
        "name": "value1",
        "test": "blah1"
    },
    {
        "name": "value2",
        "test": "blah2"
    }
]
```

Comment: The _whole point_ of `--arg` is to pass your content as data so it can't possibly be misinterpreted as code or syntax.

Comment: ...whereas when you add quotes and commas, those are syntax.

Comment: ...if you _want_ to pass a list, then pass an actual list -- use `--argjson`, and rewrite your query to work with same.

Comment: (and don't use `-r` when you're emitting JSON instead of raw string data as output).

Comment: Welcome to SO, and kudos for including a short, simple, self-contained example (MCVE)! It makes everything easier both for people answering now, and for future readers who come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--arg` will treat your value as a literal string, so the quotes and commas won't have any effect.

You can instead format your list as a valid JSON list, and use `--argjson`:

```
testValues='[ "value1", "value2" ]'
jq --argjson TESTVALUES "$testValues" '.[] | select(.name==($TESTVALUES[]))' file.json
```

Or perhaps even better, specify some delimiter and have jq split up your string instead, so you don't have to worry about JSON escaping:

```
testValues='value1,value2'
jq --arg TESTVALUES "$testValues" '.[] | select(.name==($TESTVALUES | split(",")[]))' file.json
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you for the solution and also for providing 2 different ways to accomplish this.